# Создать массив для каждого элемента DOM

Tags: jquery, массивы, dom

Подскажите, как создать массив для каждого элемента DOM, у которого `data` атрибут `data-seq=1`?
В идеале, нужны массивы с индексами по их `ID`, например:

```
 array["id"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var arr = {}; 

  $('*').each(function() {

    var data_seq = $(this).attr('data-seq'); // Получаем атрибут data-seq

    if (data_seq == 1) {              
      var current_id = $(this).attr('id');   // Получаем id
      arr[current_id] = [];                  // Добавляяем в массив
    }

  });

  arr.p.push("Paragraph value");
  arr.div.push("Div value");
  
  console.log(arr);             
  console.log(Object.keys(arr)); // Если отдельно нужны ключи
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="div" data-seq=1></div>
  <p id="p" data-seq=1></p>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Подскажите,а добавлять данные в эти массивы я смогу путем команды arr.div.push() и arr.p.push() ?

Comment: @Batyabest, **обновил**.